# Should the gas be turned off before leaving on vacation?

Tags: gas

I have not seen this recommended in most lists of things to do before going on vacation. Wouldn't turning off the gas main prevent issues if there is a gas leak or a fire?

Is there a certain set of conditions or situations when you should turn off the gas?

Comment: In the past it would cause issues when people returned and forgot to relight pilots. Additionally most homes with gas use it for heating, making it unwise to turn it off during cold weather vacations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, turning off your gas will prevent issues if there is a gas leak. I never have but I do turn off my water in case of a leak and oil burner to prevent wasting fuel. Turning off gas will be a personal preference, just as turning off the water is.  You will need to consider what you have for appliances and how much hassle they will be to relight or if you need them to run (like a furnace during cold months to prevent pipe freezing) and whether turning it off will help you relax more while on vacation or not. Some people turn off everything, some don't do anything.  Like I said, it's a personal preference.

Comment: I prefer to turn down the thermostat and leave everything else alone.  That way my pipes don't freeze and I don't have to relight pilot lights when I get back.  If I lived in a really old house with questionable gas appliances, I might consider turning it off.  But, even before that, I'd consider fixing the hazards in my home so it's safe enough to live in it.

Comment: You could also drain the pipes to prevent frost damage, but that assumes it is possible to properly drain them including any low spots that will invariable be hiding everywhere.